# Add `alt` parameter while generating reports from AdExchange Seller API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to retrieve a report from the [AdExchange Seller API](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/seller-rest/). 
I am using the maximum allowed amount of dimensions and metrics so the reports is quite big (>100.000 rows). According to the [documentation on large reports](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/seller-rest/reporting/large-reports) this is possible using the limit break feature by adding the `alt=media` parameter. But I can't figure out how to add that parameter using the [Google API client for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). I would prefer to stick to the official Google libraries, but I'm open for suggestions.

Note: adding `alt=csv` or `alt=media` to the `optParams` does not work and I can easily access the data if I remove some of the dimensions and metrics.

More specifically I'm using the `accounts_reports` resource and then the `generate` method. Looking at the source code (shown below), I can't see anywhere that it would be able to accept a `alt` parameter, but I'm obviously missing something.

```
$this->accounts_reports = new Google_Service_AdExchangeSeller_Resource_AccountsReports(
        $this,
        $this->serviceName,
        'reports',
        array(
          'methods' => array(
            'generate' => array(
              'path' => 'accounts/{accountId}/reports',
              'httpMethod' => 'GET',
              'parameters' => array(
                'accountId' => array(
                  'location' => 'path',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'required' => true,
                ),
                'startDate' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'required' => true,
                ),
                'endDate' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'required' => true,
                ),
                'dimension' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'repeated' => true,
                ),
                'filter' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'repeated' => true,
                ),
                'locale' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'string',
                ),
                'maxResults' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'integer',
                ),
                'metric' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'repeated' => true,
                ),
                'sort' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'repeated' => true,
                ),
                'startIndex' => array(
                  'location' => 'query',
                  'type' => 'integer',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        )
    );
```

Digging further I found this statement in the `Google_Service_AdExchangeSeller_Resource_AccountsReports` class.

> Generate an Ad Exchange report based on the report request sent in the query
>      parameters. Returns the result as JSON; to retrieve output in CSV format
>      specify "alt=csv" as a query parameter. (reports.generate)

But how exactly would that work? As far as I can figure out, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer but to long for a comment.

I don't think you are going to get that to work with the client library.  The client libraries are generated via the Discovery Services API.  Which gives information about what parameters the API takes. For some reason this `alt=csv` is not registered in the discovery services for that API. Its there in the description but its not registered as a parameter.  So the Client library itself isn't going to build it for you.

You can see the response I am looking at [here](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/adexchangeseller/v2.0/rest)

An idea would be to make the change to the client library yourself you have the code.  While altering the client libraries manually is not ideal it is doable. 
Try and add alt and give it a value of CSV.

I don't have enough experience with the inner workings of the PHP client library but you can post this as an [issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) on their forum.  Mention that its not in discovery they may have an easer way of applying a random parameter to the query string.   I doubt it but its worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm glad that somebody can confirm my sanity. I actually tried changing the client library code, but I didn't spend too much time trying. I might try again soon. I did realise however, that adding the alt=media parameter, will actually return the csv file gzipped, as specified in the documentation. So I will use that solution for now. Thanks for answering. I will mark your's as correct.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with the PHP client library. The following example demonstrates how to do it with the Drive API:

```
$fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
$content = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
  'alt' => 'media' ));
```

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#examples

Comment: Hi there! True, it should. But adding the `alt=media` parameter actually works. And doing the same with csv doesn't as far as I can tell.